# Add RightButtonItem to navigation bar when displaying tabbarcontroller views

Tags: ios, navigationbar, tabbarcontroller, rightbarbuttonitem

In my application I have `tabbarcontroller` that is not the first `viewcontroller`. It will open form a `navigationcontroller`.(by pushing it to stack from its parent)

Now I want to add a rightbarbuttonitem to the navigationbar of this view. I am using this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *b= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(actionBarButtonPressed)];
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem= b;
```

but it is not working-any buttons do not appear in the navigation bar. I searched about this but in all topic this codes has been answered as working solution. Maybe it should be different when using `tabbar` and `navigationbar` together. Does any one know any other working solutions.

**Edit**
I add a break point ad last line and checked some variables. This is the result:

```
(lldb) po self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
error: property 'navigationItem' not found on object of type 'id'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po self.navigationController;
 nil
(lldb) po self.navigationItem;
<UINavigationItem: 0x8997070>
(lldb) 
(lldb) po self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
error: property 'navigationItem' not found on object of type 'id'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

It seems that `navigationController` is `nil` and we directly should call `navigationItem`. So I changed the code but again not working. So I checked these variables:

```
(lldb) po self.navigationItem
<UINavigationItem: 0x8d789c0>
(lldb) po self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
error: property 'rightBarButtonItem' not found on object of type 'id'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb)
```

it seems that `rightbarbuttonitem` is not exist. So what should we do now?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to that line and use `po` in the console to check if `self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` exists.

Comment: I do not used console and 'po' till now and I am not familiar with them. let me search to check how it works.

Comment: Where did you add your `UIBarButtonItem` code? Into one of the view controllers on into the tab bar controller?

Comment: on 'viewdidload' of all 'viewcontrollers'

Comment: You have to add this into the tab bar controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't change the right bar button item is because only your tab bar controller is in the navigation controller stack. The view controllers only have access to the tab bar controller.

So in order to have a custom navigation bar button, you have to add/set it in your `UITabBarController`.

If you'd like to have different `UIBarButtons` for each of your view controllers, there the delegate method `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` where you can change the UIBarButtonItem based on the selected view controller.

Comment: How can we add it to uibarbuttoncontroller? Does it accept barbuttonitems too?

Comment: UIBarButtonController? Just add your code to the UITabBarController's class.

Answer (score 1):

If your view is:`TabBarController` ==> `NavigationController` ==>`YourViewController`

To set `UIBarButtonItem` like this:

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(doSome)];
```